# Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: solidity

[image: Solidity function]
I am having trouble running this code, its giving me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: VM Exception while processing transaction.

Please help, it works in the Remix ide but when i use it with my UI it doesn't work and even if I'm using the console on chrome it does't work

Comment: Please include code as text in the question. The error message says you are out of gas. What happens if you set a higher gas limit in the transaction?

Comment: i raised the gas limit to 7000000 and now it's saying 'revert' instead of gas

Comment: I'm not an oracle.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please format your question correctly so that we can help you best.  Without knowing what you're trying to do and what functions you are calling (since you just say "trouble with this code" and not which of the two functions is giving the error) how are we supposed to magically solve your problem?

If I had to guess what the problem is here are my ideas:

- You are not the admin and are calling addUser which has the only_admin modifier.
- `stakeholders.push(_address) - 1` is causing issues as I have no idea what you are subtracting 1 from.
- You're not connected to a proper network (mainnnet, kovan, ropsten, etc...)

The more information you give, the more willing people will be to help you and they'll be able to help you more accurately.